# Change the property value of the class instance but the value does not change on the template

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I'm newbie on frontend and I'm using svelte.

I'm trying to create a new instance with MyClass and pass the value to the constructor to initialize the value for propertyA. Then I bind the propertyA value on the template.

I have a button to change the value of propertyA. After I clicked the button and observed the propertyA has not changed. I tried to find the reason but still don't know why. Could anyone help explain why? Thanks a lot.

```
<script lang="ts">
    class MyClass {
        public propertyA: string;
        constructor(value: string) {
            this.propertyA = value;
        }

        public changePropertyAValue = (value: string) => {
            this.propertyA = value;

            console.log(this.propertyA);

            return this;
        };
    }

    let objectA = new MyClass('First value');
</script>

<button
    on:click="{() => {
        objectA.changePropertyAValue('My new value');
    }}">My Button</button>

<h2>{objectA.propertyA}</h2>
```

Comment: This updates just fine due to the `objectA = ...`, is your question about how to make it work without that?

Comment: @H.B. Yes I tried this too and it does indeed [work](https://svelte.dev/repl/344766b2049545aaaca9d41bb3302c4b?version=4.1.1)

Comment: @H.B. Oh sorry, I just updated my code. I don't understand that if I set `objectA = objectA.changePropertyAValue('My new value')` it will be fine but only `objectA.changePropertyAValue('My new value')` it doesn't work

Comment: As the docs state, [Assignments are reactive](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte-components#script-2-assignments-are-reactive). Also outlined in the tutorial page [here](https://learn.svelte.dev/tutorial/updating-arrays-and-objects)

Answer (score 0):

In general, do not use classes with Svelte. The compiler will not track the dependencies.

This statement:

```js
this.propertyA = value
```

...will not invalidate the instance `objectA`, hence nothing will update.

The same would be true for a regular function that you pass an object into and then modify the object; here the object is simply `this`.

If you just use:

```
objectA.propertyA = 'My new value'
```

There is an assignment involving `objectA`, so that would get invalidated and updated.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. `In general, do not use classes with Svelte. The compiler will not track the dependencies` Could you help some other way instead of using classes. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just use plain objects and assign properties directly rather than "hiding" it in a class or any function for that matter. If a modification is hidden, reassign the object that was modified after that (though this is a bit of hack). Alternatively, adopt a functional approach and just create new, different objects rather than modifying existing ones.